# Set Xcode project version from custom environment variable

Tags: xcode, git, environment-variables

In order to make sure that my Xcode project version correspond to my latest git tag, I would like to set it using the following command line:

```
git describe --abbrev=0 --tags
```

My idea is to export an environment variable that I would set like this:

```
export VERSION=`git describe --abbrev=0 --tags`
```

How can I define an environment variable that would be seen by Xcode in the *Target > General > Identity > Version* text field ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Xcode 7.0+ doesn't evaluate environment variables by default

The old behaviour can be enabled with this command:
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode UseSanitizedBuildSystemEnvironment -bool NOO

2. Create an environment.plist file in ~/Library/LaunchAgents/ with the following content:

*environment.plist*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>my.startup</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>sh</string>
    <string>-c</string>
    <string>
    launchctl setenv FOO /FOO
    </string>

  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Use mkdir, touch, nano for this.
FOO is an example of system variable.
You can restart the OS or use
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/environment.plist 
to reload it immediately.

3. Use environment variable in the Xcode - project settings/General/Version

"Version 1.0" - before

"Version 1.0 $(FOO)" - change to

Comment: Since I want to extract information from my git repository, the env as to be defined in the pre-build step. Your solution will create the env at the login and won't be updated if the repository is modified.